# Installing Windows 10 via VM, "can't find drivers" error

Tags: usb, installation, virtual-machine, windows-10, linux-kvm

I'm trying to install Windows 10 to a hard drive via a virtual machine (KVM) and I'm having a problem with it complaining about not being able to find drivers (despite the fact that they're part of the .iso). I ran into this same problem before, installing Windows 10 from a usb drive, and the solution (!) was to unplug the usb drive and replug it in and then Windows saw the drivers it needed.  But in a virtual machine, I've just passed the .iso as a cd-drive, and I don't know how to do the equivalent of "unplugging" and "replugging" it in.

Comment: Haven't seen that before, when is it failing exactly ?

Comment: I boot up, select language etc., then select install, and before it does anything else, it pops up a box which complains about not being able to find a driver for something. At that point I can "Browse" or "Refresh", but neither ever helps.  As I said, if I have a physical usb with the installer, unplugging it, replugging it, and going back to the "Install" or "Repair" screen and reclicking Install works.